# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am migrating from normal SQL to PDO because I let a friend of mine test if I have any weak points and he adviced me to PDO because he found a lot of weak points.

So here is my full error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' in /home/ubuntu/workspace/post.php on line 54
>
> ( ! ) PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '? (`id`, `title`, `info_bys`, `info_shorts`, `info_longs`, `email`, ' at line 1 in /home/ubuntu/workspace/post.php on line 54

And here is my code:

```
    $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO  :portal
    (`id`, `title`, `info_bys`, `info_shorts`, `info_longs`, `email`, `filename`, `filepath`, `filename2`, `filepath2`, `approved`) 
    VALUES ('', ':title', ':by_information', ':short', ':long_information', ':email', ':filename', ':filetarget', ':filename2', ':filetarget2',  'false'");
    $stmt->execute(array(':portal' => $portal, ':title' => $title, ':by_information' => $by_information, ':short' => $short, ':long_information' => $long_information, ':email' => $email, ':filename' => $fileName, ':filetarget' => $fileTarget, ':filename2' => $fileName2, ':filetarget2' => $fileTarget ));
    echo $affected_rows.' were affected';
```

Is there something I cant use in PDO that I can use in SQL or am I just typing the wrong stuff.

Hope someone can help.

EDIT:

New code:

```
    function buildQuery( $get_var ) 
{
    switch($get_var)
    {
        case 1:
        $portal = $_POST['portal'];
            break;
    }

                $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO  :portal
            (`id`, `title`, `info_bys`, `info_shorts`, `info_longs`, `email`, `filename`, `filepath`, `filename2`, `filepath2`, `approved`) 
            VALUES (:title, :by_information, :short, :long_information, :email, :filename, :filetarget, :filename2, :filetarget2,  'false'");
            $stmt->execute(array(':portal' => $portal, ':title' => $title, ':by_information' => $by_information, ':short' => $short, ':long_information' => $long_information, ':email' => $email, ':filename' => $fileName, ':filetarget' => $fileTarget, ':filename2' => $fileName2, ':filetarget2' => $fileTarget ));
            echo $affected_rows.' were affected';
}
```

Comment: Table names can't be bound. You can make a whitelist can compare the name against that then just pass it in.

Comment: Ow yea I see. Im just a dumb fool. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Three issues with the code:

1. As stated by crhis85 (upvote), you can't bind table names.
2. PDO prepare takes care of the escaping **and** quotes.

   VALUES ('', ':title', ':by_information', ':short', ':long_information', ':email', ':filename', ':filetarget', ':filename2', ':filetarget2',  'false'");

The issue here is that if you define a param to a string (`PDO::PARAM_STR`) the values are double quoted with single quotes. Instead do this:

```
`VALUES ('', :title, :by_information, :short, ....");`
```

3. Don't insert an ID, this should be set on auto increment and is done automatically.

   `'INSERT INTO  table (title, ...'`

Also, backticks (``) are used to let the database driver know that you're *using* this value and is not to be used as a reserved keyword. In other words, entirely obsolete in this query.

Comment: It doesnt return any errors but it doesnt give me the text that is set,
This : echo $affected_rows.' were affected';

Comment: @RikNijdeken update the question to your new code.

Comment: @RikNijdeken `:portal` still needs to be `$portal`, and that should be checked before being passed in. `id` shouldn't be passed in, and you should give `approved` a default value of `false`.

Comment: @RikNijdeken `"INSERT INTO  $portal (\`title\`, ... ";`

Comment: @chris85 I edited it but it still doesnt work.

Comment: try: `echo $stmt->rowCount() . ' rows were affected.';`.

Comment: @Xorifelse Still doesnt give me an echo with "Bla Bla" were affected

Comment: @RikNijdeken where is `$affected_rows` defined? What is `$_POST['portal']`?

Comment: @chris85 Ow what wait, Thanks for noticing :P I think its old code. And $_POST['portal'] is a posted select value

Comment: @RikNijdeken I know that. If it is a reserved term though this will also fail because it isn't in backticks.

Comment: @chris85 How do i backtick it then?

Comment: Something like `"\`" . $_POST['portal'] . "\`"` **BUT** check that value first. Otherwise preparing is almost useless because you are just passing in user provided data to query.

Comment: `"\`{$_POST['portal']}\`"` would work too, but you should whitelist it.

Comment: @chris85 I am checking every input field earlier in the code. I'll check it out.

Comment: Giving me another error:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '`' in /home/ubuntu/workspace/post.php on line 61
Already fixed it i used ' instead of "
But it still didnt work

Comment: @RikNijdeken didnt insert...or? update question..

Comment: @chris85 It didnt insert the data that I put in the form.

Comment: Let us continue this discussion in [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107174/xorifelses-room)